# Delphi - последний запущенный поток

Tags: mysql, delphi, многопоточность, grid

Есть запрос MySQL, выполняется долго, поэтому выполняю его в потоке. Использую для этого TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(). Написал такую процедуру:

```
Procedure DualThreadEvent (pThreadProc:TProc;MainThreadProc:TProc);
Begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread (Procedure Begin
      Try
         if Assigned (pThreadProc) then
            pThreadProc;
      Except
        On EAbort Do Exit;
      End;
      if Assigned (MainThreadProc) then
        TThread.Queue(NIL,Procedure Begin
           MainThreadProc;
        End);
  End).Start;
End;
```

Соответственно, в нужном месте ее вызываю:

```
DualThreadEvent(
    Procedure
    Begin
      if Not _Alive.V then
        Exit;
    // Обращение к БД и запись данных в заранее созданный класс
    End,
    Procedure
    Begin
      if not _Alive.V then
        Exit;
    // Запись из класса в DBGrid
    End);
```

Разумеется, проблема в том, что неизвестно, когда закончится какой тред. Допустим, юзер внес изменение в грид, оно записалось в БД, сразу после этого начинает идти запрос. Но тут же юзер решает отфильтровать датасет по какому-то полю, и это уже другой запрос. Но никто не гарантирует, что последний запрос выполнится позже. В итоге может быть ситуация, что предыдущий запрос выполняется позже последнего, и юзеру высвечивается не та инфа, которую он искал. Причем иногда уже после отображения правильной инфы.

Какой правильный способ такого избежать? Спасибо!

Comment: Завести диспетчера, который записывает очередность запросов?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то нужно по завершению Вашего трудоемкого процесса вызывать `Thread.Terminate` исполняющего его потока. таким образом вы будете знать о состоянии потока на данный момент и создать диспетчер очереди который будет ставить все остальные вызовы в очередь, и смотреть за состоянием исполняемого потока, и соответственно запускать задачу только после того как текущий поток изменит свой статус terminated